# Getting 'UnableToDeserializePostBody' error after sending a post request to Microsoft Calender Create Event Api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, httpresponse

Below is the json which i am passing with the access token and the application/json content type.

```
{
    "isOnlineMeeting": true,
    "subject": "Work Today",
    "attendees": [
        {
            "emailAddress": {
                "address": "mohit.gupta@caleedo.com",
                "name": "Mohit Gupta"
            },
            "type": "required"
        }
    ],
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2023-05-04T16:00:00",
        "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
    },
    "onlineMeetingProvider": "teamsForBusiness",
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2023-05-04T16:30:00",
        "timeZone": "India Standard Time"
    },
    "body": {
        "subject": "HTML",
        "content": "I am working hard"
    }
}
```

After the POST request on this api - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

```
POST /users/{id}}/calendar/events
```

I am getting the below error.
Exception occurred
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request:

```
[
    {
        "error": {
            "code": "UnableToDeserializePostBody",
            "message": "were unable to deserialize "
        }
    }
]
```

Not able to find the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that issue is in

```
...
"body": {
    "subject": "HTML",
    "content": "I am working hard"
}
...
```

the property should be `contentType` not `subject`

```
"body": {
    "contentType": "HTML",
    "content": "I am working hard"
}
```